# How can I hide browser broken default image added on empty src <img /> with css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**How can I hide browser broken default image added on empty src  with css ?**

```css
img
{
  background-color:red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img src="" />
```